# How to make a scrolling starfield

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a simple scrolling right to left `starfield`. I have printed out the stars randomly. Now, how do I target each star and randomly give it a speed (say 1-10) and begin moving it? I also need to put each star back on the right edge after it reaches the left edge.

Following is my code written so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>


 function stars()
 {
    canvas = document.getElementById("can");

    if(canvas.getContext)
    {
       ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
       ctx.fillStyle = "black";
       ctx.rect (0, 0, 400, 400);
       ctx.fill();
       starfield();
    }
  }
  //print  random stars
  function starfield()
  {
     for (i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*399);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*399);
        var tempx = x;
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
     }
  }

</script>

</head>
<body onload="stars()">
<h1>Stars</h1>
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="400"style="border:2px solid #000100" ></canvas>
</body >
</html>
```

Comment: Are you ok with a jQuery soution?

Comment: sorry I don't use jquery. still trying to learn js at the moment :)

Comment: You just have to import an external file for the answer that i posted using jQuery solution

Comment: Check my answer.If it works perfectly for you then i can post the entire code for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [quick demo](http://codepen.io/Jet/pen/gwFGl) on Codepen. After saving the stars in an array, I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` to run the drawing code and update the position on every frame.

```
function stars() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("can");
  console.log(canvas);
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    ctx.fill();
    starfield();
  }
}
// Create random stars with random velocity.
var starList = []
function starfield() {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var star = {
      x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 399),
      y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 399),
      vx: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
    };
    starList.push(star);
  }
}

function run() {
  // Register for the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(run);

  // Reset the canvas
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  ctx.fill();

  // Update position and draw each star.
  var star;
  for(var i=0, j=starList.length; i<j; i++) {
    star = starList[i];
    star.x = (star.x - star.vx + 400) % 400;
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(star.x, star.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

stars();
run();
```

Comment: that's what I was trying to do! so as barry above said I need to put the stars locations into an array and update each cycle. thanks mildy.

Comment: +1 for using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` here instead of `settimeout()` or `setinterval()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `x,y` coordinates in an array, and then make a function that draws the array.

```
var stars = [
  {x:110, y:80},
  {x:120, y:20},
  {x:130, y:60},
  {x:140, y:40}
]
```

Then make a function to alter the `x,y` coordinates (for example increment `y=y+1`) each time before using the draw function.

**Bonus:**
This array solution allows you to have each star move at its own speed, you could store a delta (say 1 upto 3) in that array, and do `y=y+delta` instead. This looks 3D.
You could even go further and have a seperate x and y delta, and have stars fly out from the middle, which is even more 3D!

Or even simpler/faster could be to have the render function accept an x,y offset. It could then even wrap around, so that what falls off the screen on one side comes back on the other. It looks like you are rotating in space.

Comment: thanks barry. I haven't quite got the hang of arrays yet. ill try to do one where I just move one star and go from there.

Comment: These stars are an excellent project to start experimenting with arrays. Good luck! 

If you find a function that can print the whole array, such as `console.log(stars)` or `console.table(stars)`, that might come in handy when debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

I simple way to imitate star movement towards a point(like a center) is simply divide both X and Y by Z coordinate.

`nx = x / z
ny = y / z`

And simply decrease z value as you iterate. As z is big, your points will be around a point and as z decreases the result will be bigger and bigger which imitates "moving" of a stars.

Answer (score 0):

Just providing a solution which uses **jQuery** because using it you can get the output with lesser lines of code compared to complete canvas solution.It uses two canvas divs to get the desired output:

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/M2u8r/)

**Little updated code from the code posted in the question**

```
<script>
 function stars(){
     canvas = document.getElementById("can1");
     canvasCopy = document.getElementById("can2");

 if(canvas.getContext){
         ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         ctx.fillStyle = "black";
         ctx.rect (0, 0, 400, 400);
         ctx.fill();
         starfield();
         var destCtx = canvasCopy.getContext('2d');
         destCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
     }
 }
//print  random stars
function starfield(){
    for (i=0;i<10;i++){
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*399);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*399);
        var tempx = x;
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
</script>

<body onload="stars()">
<h1>Stars</h1>
    <div id="starBlocks">
    <canvas id="can1" width="400" height="400"style="border:2px solid #000100" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="can2" width="400" height="400"style="border:2px solid #000100" ></canvas>
    </div>
</body >
```

**jQuery**

```
function playStars()
{
    $('#starBlocks').animate({
        scrollLeft : 400
    },10000,'linear',function(){
        $('#starBlocks').scrollLeft(0);
        playStars();
    });
}
playStars();
```

**CSS**

```
#starBlocks{
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks zword. sorry I don't use jquery as of yet. still struggling with js! :)

Comment: @user2827914 you just need to import a single external js file for using the above code in my answer